# Minimum obs from dataset to cover all required levels

Tags: algorithm, sas, minimum

I'm stumped.

I want to reduce a really big data-set to fewer observations, but containing all the levels of the original data-set (at most) once. This would be done for testing purposes, so it's in our best interest to come up with final data-set that has least number of obs.

So if we take data-set SASHELP.CLASS for example. I would like to find out the first obs (or any non-specific obs really, but i feel it might be easier with first/last obs) that covers each individual levels of the original data-set, **not** all possible (existing, or theoretical) combinations of the required variables.

Output would look something like this: (SASHELP.CLASS: all levels by AGE, SEX):

- AGE has 6 distinct levels (11-16)
- SEX has 2 distinct levels ("F", "M")
- Least number of obs covering those levels theoretically is 6.

So we should end up with:

- OBS #1: Affred, "M", 14
- OBS #2: Alice, "F", 13

*Barbara, Carol, and Henry will not be output, as both F-M and 13-14 are covered*

- OBS #3: James, "M", 12
- OBS #4: Janet, "F", 15
- OBS #5: Joyce, "F", 11
- OBS #6: Philip, "M", 16

*end of output*

In this case we went through data sequentially, and we've found minimum number of obs (6) satisfying the requirement, but if the levels get more lengthy (or inter-correlated), and data assorted (supposed we could pre-sort), we might end up with something that is close to minimum, but not quite minimum of longest level among required variables.

I would imagine this would require some sort of recursive algorithm to get most efficiently small number of obs to cover the values, but have no clue where to start. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need additional data beyond the class variables (here, age and sex) from the rows?  If so, how much of it - another variable or two, or many, and ordinal or discrete?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very efficient approach, but it gives the desired result

```
/* sort by first key */
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=minset;
 by age;
run;

/* set wantflag to 1 if first.key else wantflag is 0 */
data minset;
 set minset;
 by age;
 if first.age then wantflag = 1;
 else wantflag = 0;
run;

/* repeat proc sort and next data step for each consecutive key */
/* sort by second key and by descending wantflag */
proc sort data=minset out=minset;
 by sex descending wantflag ;
run;

/* set wantflag to 1 if first.key, do NOT set to 0 if not key */
data minset;
 set minset;
 by sex;
 if first.sex then wantflag = 1;
run;

/* finally keep smallest possible dataset */
data minset (drop=wantflag );
 set minset;
 if wantflag eq 1 then output;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want an algorithm that is fairly easy to implement and produces a good (but not necessarily the best) results.

My approach would be to start with the rarest levels.

Step 1. Sort all categories according to level frequency.

In your example we might get:

```
AGE
14 117
13 119
11 140
12 154
15 165
16 170

SEX
M 503
F 524
```

Step 2. Start with the rarest remaining level. In our case AGE=14.

Then take the rarest remaining level in (each of) the remaining categories.
If you get a match, then use that as a sample. If not, then increase the search into more frequent levels until you get a hit. Tick off the levels you have found.

In SQL you could do this with `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT <primary key>, 
   case when category2 = <lowest remaining freq level for category2> then 1
        when category2 = <second lowest remaining freq level for category2> then 2
        ...
   end case AS category2,
   case when category3 = <lowest remaining freq level for category3> then 1
        when category3 = <second lowest remaining freq level for category3> then 2
        ...
   end case AS category3
FROM table1
WHERE category1 = <lowest remaining freq level for category1>
ORDER BY category2, category3
```

Repeat step 2 until all levels are represented.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data set and use the `by` statement in the data step to output only the first group.

Note this is updated from my previous post.  As others pointed out, it was incorrect.

```
proc sort data=SASHELP.CLASS out=class_temp;
by AGE descending sex;
run;

data class_temp;
set class_temp;
by AGE;
if first.age then output;
run;

proc sort data=SASHELP.CLASS out=class_temp2;
by sex descending AGE;
run;

data class_temp2;
set class_temp2;
by sex;
if first.sex then output;
run;

proc sort data=class_temp2;
by age;
run;

data combos;
merge class_temp class_temp2;
by age sex;
run;
```

Comment: This will not give the desired result if for each age there is at least one observations for each sex.

Comment: re-read the second paragraph, "... that covers each individual levels of the original data-set, not all possible (existing, or theoretical) combinations of the required variables."

Comment: I agree with Laurent here, I think this won't quite give the desired results.  It would give F 13  and F 14 then later M 13 and M 14, which is not desired; he'd want F 13 F 14 M 13 and not the M 14 from that set of 4).

Comment: You are correct.  I am updating the post to fix. -- this basically Laurent's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something that would do roughly this with a hash object.  The downside of this is that it isn't perfect - the example I list gives one extra item beyond what you would want, because the order of interacting with the cells matters; and the initial order of the dataset affects the diversity of the output, so in the example below you have a lot of female records and only two male records, not reflecting the diversity of the initial dataset, simply because (in my sashelp.class, at least)  there happen to be females before males for most ages.

```
data want;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
  declare hash recs();
  recs.defineKey('keytype');
  recs.defineKey('keylist');
  recs.defineData('keydata');
  recs.defineDone();
  format keylist $10. keytype $8. keydata $8.;
  call missing(of keylist keytype keydata);
end;
set sashelp.class;
  agechar=put(age,3.);
  rc_age = recs.check(key: 'age', key:agechar);  
  rc_sex = recs.check(key:'sex',key:sex);
  rc = rc_age+rc_sex;
  if rc=0 then delete;
  else do;
    if rc_age ne 0 then recs.add(key:'age',key:agechar,data:'sex');
    if rc_sex ne 0 then recs.add(key:'sex',key:sex,data:'sex');
    output;
  end;
run;
```

It checks the hash for each key separately, and if a record is found with an not-yet-found key it populates the dataset and the hash with those key(s).  It does not go back and check later to see if there is a better solution, although you could run this a few times with different (random) sort orders on the incoming dataset and keep the smallest dataset.